# python find and match exact string

Tags: python, string, csv, string-matching, export-to-csv

How can I match a string from a column in a `.csv` file against a list of defined datatypes?

The list of data types is:

```
Datatype = ["M", "B", "E", "A", "DF", "DW", "DL", "DT", "XTEXT", "MDEDATA"]
```

I want to use the data type that matches the column to look up a value in a dictionary.

#### What works

When my code finds something like `DW1` in the input (see below for examples) it writes `DW:5` to the output file, and when it finds `DT34` it writes `DT:7`. This works fine.

#### What doesn't work

But the problem is, whenever my code comes across `XTEXT` it matches it first to `E: 2` (because `E` is present in `XTEXT`) and *then* to `XTEXT: 4105` in the next row. As a result, the corresponding line in the output file contains `2` instead of `4105`. Something similar happens for `MDEDATA` which is resolved to `A:3`.

I tried using a regex to remove numbers from the relevant columns in the input file (this line is commented out in the code above), like this:

```
if (Datatype[n] == re.sub('[1234567890\n]', '', line.split(";")[1])):
    # ...
```

but this causes problems when encountering strings like `X256DATA`.

Another issue is that the output file that is produced currently displays `abc;DW1` in the first column and `5` in the second column, but I want `abc` in the first column, `DW1` in the second and `5` in the third column!

How can I solve these problems? Any help appreciated.

---

#### CSV example

Input:

```
1 abc DW1  
2 uz5 XTEXT
```

Current output:

```
1 abc DW1    5
2 uz5 XTEXT  4105
```

#### TXT example

Input:

```
abc;DW1\n  
uz5;XTEXT\n
```

Current output:

```
abc;DW1,5\n  
uz5;XTEXT,4105\n
```

#### Desired output

```
abc;DW1;5\n  
uz5;XTEXT;4105\n
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. Can you please provide some example input (i.e., an excerpt from the CSV file you are parsing) and the code you are using to transform it into `dict1` / `dict2`?

Comment: How do you query the dictionary?

Comment: @vinu Thanks for adding your code. But what about the example input data? It would be great if you could provide even a single line...

Comment: @vinu Great! Now just add what you want these two lines to look like in the output file. I know you are describing it in the text, but seeing input and *desired* output next to each other will bring us closer to finding a solution. (Another reason I'm asking for this is that I have a feeling your code can probably be shortened significantly, and still do what you want.)

Comment: @vinu OK, I will try and work this out in an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal dictionary lookup matches the key exactly. If you get multiple matches you are doing something else.

```
>>> dict1 = {"M":1, "E":2, "A":3, "DF":4, "DW":5, "DL":6, "DT":7, "B":10, "XTEXT":4105, "MDEDATA":4110}
>>> dict1["XTEXT"]
4105
```

Now from the updated question I see you are not really looking for exact matches, as `DW1` in file should match `DW` in `Datatype`. If you want to check if the beginning of the string matches, use `str.startswith`:

```
>>> "DW1".startswith("DW")
True
```

Note that you must check `MDEDATA` before `M` to avoid a false match. More generally, check longer matches before shorter ones.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a solution based on your code that should work for the format of your `.txt` files:

```
import csv

# Define data_type / dict1 / dict2:

data_type = [
    "M", "E", "B", "A", "DF", "DW", "DL", "DT", "PF", "PW", "PL", "PT",
    "XTEXT", "MDEDATA", "X8DATA", "X16DATA", "X32DATA", "X64DATA",
    "X128DATA", "X256DATA", "X512DATA", "X1024DATA", "X2048DATA",
    "X4096DATA", "X8912DATA"]

dict1 = {
    "M": 1, "E": 2, "A": 3, "DF": 4, "DW": 5, "DL": 6, "DT": 7, "PF": 8,
    "PW": 9, "B": 10, "PL": 11, "PT": 12, "XTEXT": 4105, "MDEDATA": 4110,
    "X8DATA": 10000, "X16DATA": 10001, "X32DATA": 10002, "X64DATA": 10003,
    "X128DATA": 10004, "X256DATA": 10005, "X512DATA": 10006,
    "X1024DATA": 10007, "X2048DATA": 10008, "X4096DATA": 10009,
    "X8912DATA": 10010}

dict2 = {
    "M": "B", "E": "B", "A": "B", "DF": ">f","PF": ">f", "DW": ">h",
    "PW": ">h", "DL": ">l", "PL": ">l", "DT": "String", "PT": "String",
    "B": "B", "XTEXT": "XTEXT", "MDEDATA": "MDEDATA", "X8DATA": "X8DATA",
    "X16DATA": "X16DATA", "X32DATA": "X32DATA", "X64DATA": "X64DATA",
    "X128DATA": "X128DATA", "X256DATA": "X256DATA", "X512DATA": "X512DATA",
    "X1024DATA": "X1024DATA", "X2048DATA": "X2048DATA",
    "X4096DATA": "X4096DATA", "X8912DATA": "X8912DATA"}

# Obtain writer for output file:

source = 'GSV.txt'
dest = open('GSV_copy.txt', 'w')

# Process data:

import re

source_lines = open(source).readlines()
for line in source_lines:
    x = line.split(';')[1]
    icon_lletter = ''
    icon_lnummer = 0
    python_letter = ''
    for t in data_type:
        if x.startswith(t): # Alternative using re: "if re.match(t, x)"
            icon_lletter = t
            break
    if (icon_lletter not in dict1):
        print "Entry (%s) in Dictionary1 is not available" % (icon_lletter)
    else:
        icon_lnummer = dict1[icon_lletter]
    if (icon_lletter not in dict2):
        print "Entry (%s) in Dictionary2 is not available" % (icon_lletter)
    else:
        python_letter = dict2[icon_lletter]
        print "Converted the GVR datatype to python datatype is %s : %s : %s" \
            % (icon_lletter, python_letter, icon_lnummer)
        # Write line to output file:
        dest.write(';'.join([line.strip('\n'), str(icon_lnummer) + '\n']))

dest.close()
```

**Please note:**

- With this solution I am trying to fix your problem while staying close to your original implementation. There are different ways of achieving your goal that are probably more Pythonic / efficient / DRY.
- Since your input and ouput files do not have the same number of columns and differ in terms of formatting, you will eventually want to turn the code into a (set of) function(s) that take the things that differ (file type and column to check) as parameters.

---

**Edit:**

Working on this some more I noticed that the output in `dest` was a bit garbled. (I hadn't gotten that far before :)) I've changed the code to produce the exact output you want now.

---

**Another Edit** (based on discussion in comments):

On the topic of matching data types in the input file(s) against the list of defined `data_type`s: If the `DT`s in your input file always have the numbers that you don't want to consider at the beginning or at the end, you could use

```
re.sub('^[0-9]+', '', x)
```

or

```
re.sub('[0-9]+$', '', x)
```

to remove them.

Comment: Im using python 2.7.... It throws error as --->if t.starts_with(x): 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'starts_with'

Comment: @vinu Thanks, that's a typo. It should be `t.startswith(x)`. **Edit:** Fixed in answer.

Comment: Ok, it cannot find any entry in the dictionaries!

Comment: @vinu Are you running it on the `.txt` file? I didn't change the names of the `source` and `dest` files in my answer yet... Do that and let me know if that changes anything. If it doesn't, try printing out `t` before the `break` statement to see what's going on.

Comment: @vinu What do you get when printing `t` before the break statement? Is it a key that looks like it should be in `dict1`/`dict2`?

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for your help! currently no need to bother about the pattern of the input and the output file. The main problem is parsing the strings and matching it to the defined dict! PS: for the input and output file it is easy to just copy the contents of input(.csv) file to output(.csv) file and append an extra column to the output(.csv) file with the found datatype in the dict1. This i could able to perform!

Comment: @vinu Never mind, I figured it out. The order in which we are matching `x` against `t` got mixed up. It should have been: `if x.startswith(t): ...`. I updated my answer. I also tested the code against a `.txt` file containing the example input you provided. It works now.

Comment: lol i too found the same prob and was working on that line ;)

Comment: @vinu Great, so it's doing what you want it to do now?

Comment: but still it does not work for all the DT, nevermind ill try to fix it! i need little time, in case you come with different solution or answer it would be really helpful!

Comment: @vinu I'm assuming this is the point where you would need to start using functionality provided by the `re` module to figure out if `x` and `t` are matching. Unfortunately, without seeing *all* of the data I can't really help you with that. (You shouldn't add all of the data to your post though, it's already pretty long. If you can provide a high-level description of what the data looks like, that might help.) But in general, if my answer put you on the right track, you might want to consider accepting it :)

Comment: @vinu One more idea: If the `DT`s in your input file always have the numbers that you don't want to consider when matching them against your `data_types` at the beginning or at the end, you could use `re.sub('^[0-9]+', '', x)` or `re.sub('[0-9]+$', '', x)` to remove them.

Comment: Thanks! the regex line which you suggested worked with my code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by itsjeyd,

```
re.sub('^[0-9]+', '', x) or re.sub('[0-9]+$', '', x) does the trick!
```

Comment: I am glad my suggestions helped you :) I added them to my original answer. Since it now includes all the information you needed to solve your problem(s), it would be great if you could accept it (by clicking the check mark next to it).